# Unix - how to get hostname along with domain name

Tags: solaris, hostname

In unix (solaris) is there any command where i can get hostname & domain name together??

ex. hostname -> servername domainname -> us.xyz.com

i need it output as : servername.us.xyz.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
echo `uname -n`.`awk '/^domain/ {print $2}' /etc/resolv.conf`
```

Answer (score 0):

The command `hostname` should return a FQDN assuming that it's configured correctly in /etc/nodename.

Answer (score 0):

`hostname` should return this, if it doesn't, you probably set it up wrong.
Try combining it with `domainname` in that case.

Comment: This assumes he is using NIS and assumes his NIS domain name is the same as his DNS domain name.